# Celery Async get timeout never times out

Tags: python, redis, celery, django-celery

I have my celery app as below . Am on Python 2.7.5 with celery 4.4.2 and OS is CentOs 7.4. The idea is to sign heavy files ( which takes sometimes as long as 30 mins per file when file size is in GBs ) using celery, through a shell script defined in java_zip_sign_exe variable , distributed across multiple workers running on different hosts.  sign_heavy_java_zip_files() makes async calls of sign_heavy_java_zip_file() , with all the filenames given to it.

sign_celery_app.py

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://:<hostname>:6379/0',backend='redis://:<hostname>:6379/0')
app.conf['worker_prefetch_multiplier'] = 1
app.conf['task_acks_late'] = True
app.conf.task_default_queue = 'default'
app.conf.tasks_queues = (
    Queue('default', exchange='default', routing_key='default'),
    Queue('heavy_java_zip', exchange='heavy_java_zip', routing_key='heavy_java_zip'),

@app.task

def sign_java_zip_file(filename,User,MaxPerJavaZipFileTime,Site):
  print ("Started Signing " + filename + java_zip_sign_exe )
  process=subprocess.Popen([java_zip_sign_exe,filename,User,str(MaxPerJavaZipFileTime),Site],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  out,err = process.communicate()
  print ("Finished Signing " + filename )
  return (process.returncode,out,err)

@app.task(queue='heavy_java_zip')
def sign_heavy_java_zip_files(filenames,User,MaxPerJavaZipFileTime,Site):
  job = group(sign_java_zip_file.s(filename,User,MaxPerJavaZipFileTime,Site) for filename in filenames )
  job_results=job.apply_async(queue='heavy_java_zip')
  return job_results
```

Celery worker started as below

```
celery -A sign_celery_app  worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=2  -O fair -Q "heavy_java_zip"
```

My main() python  caller file is as below

```
results_heavy_java_zip=sign_heavy_java_zip_files.delay(heavy_java_zip_file_list,User,int(MaxPerJavaZipFileTime),Site)

results_heavy_java_zip.get(timeout=(MaxTotalJavaZipTime*60))
```

When there are no workers, as expected, the timeout works with Timeout Exception raised. But if there are workers , and once the tasks have started working asynhcronously, then the timeout does not have any effect. I expected that even when they are running, they will be interrupted when the timeout is over. Is my understanding wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mistake was in the way, function call was done in the main routine.

```
results_heavy_java_zip=sign_heavy_java_zip_files.delay(heavy_java_zip_file_list,User,int(MaxPerJavaZipFileTime),Site)
```

had to be  ( no delay - or async call required from the program as its taken care in the task call )

```
results_heavy_java_zip=sign_heavy_java_zip_files(heavy_java_zip_file_list,User,int(MaxPerJavaZipFileTime),Site)
```